# Getting a div to slideDown on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am wanting a hidden div to slide down from the top of the screen when the user clicks on "Services".

When the div does slide down, I want the height to be `height: 35vh;`.

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. Does anyone see the issue?

```js
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
  $('serviceNav').addClass('active').slideDown();
  console.log('The click is working');
});
```

```css
#serviceNav {
 width: 100%;
 top: -35vh;
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#serviceNav.active {
 height: 35vh;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
 z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="serviceClick">SERVICES</li>
<div id="serviceNav"></div>
```

Comment: add dot beofre the serviceNav `$('.serviceNav').addClass('active').slideDown();`

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. It still isn't working though.

Comment: Yes, add # instead of a dot as it is Id and not a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - You need to reference the ID - `$('#serviceNav')`.
Secondly - Why are you sliding down and adding a class which moves it anyway?
Thirdly - You can't animate the `height` element, you should use `max-height`.

```
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
        $('#serviceNav').addClass('active');
        console.log('The click is working');
});


#serviceNav {
    width: 100%;
    top: -35vh;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 35vh;
    display: none;
}
#serviceNav.active {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

Edit - example: https://jsfiddle.net/664chupo/

Comment: I thought the Slidedown function animated height? At least in a sense that progression is made until the element is at its full height. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ah. Add `display: none;` to it, then add `.slideDown()` on click. I believe `slideDown()` is used for hidden elements, much like `fadeIn()`.

Comment: Edited answer - see example.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **#** in front of the ID

```js
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
  $('#serviceNav').addClass('active').slideDown();
  console.log('The click is working');
});
```

```css
#serviceNav {
 width: 100%;
 top: -35vh;
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#serviceNav.active {
 height: 35vh;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
 z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="serviceClick">SERVICES</li>
<div id="serviceNav"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code and codepen.

### HTML

```
   <li id="serviceClick">SERVICES</li>
    <div id="serviceNav">text</div>
```

### CSS

```
#serviceNav {
    width: 100%;
    top: -35vh;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#serviceNav {
    height: 0vh;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 500;
  display:none;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

### JS

```
$('#serviceClick').click( function () {
        $('#serviceNav').show();
  $('#serviceNav').css('height','35vh');
});
```

Codepen url: [codepen](https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/Ldxojx)